# Hibernate One to Many IntegrityConstraint when adding child to existing parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one, hibernate-onetomany

I have a Hibernate + Spring Boot application and I receive a IntegrityConstraintViolationException when updating a parent by adding a child.

The Database schema is:

```
table order (
  id (primary key auto generated),
);

table order_line (
  order_id (primary key + foreign key to order.id),
  order_line_id (primary key set manually set in the code),
)
```

In java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "ORDER")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "ORDER_LINE")
public class OrderLine implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private Integer orderLineId;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "Integer", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Order order;
```

To create an order, I use a JpaRepository and create my objects as following:

```
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setId(118); //This is an existing order ID which should be updated
    Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();

    OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
    orderLine.setOrderLineId(0); //This is an existing order line
    orderLine.setOrder(order);
    orderLines.add(orderLine);

    orderLine = new OrderLine();
    orderLine.setOrderLineId(1); //This is a non-existing order line
    orderLine.setOrder(order);
    orderLines.add(orderLine);

    order.setOrderLines(orderLines);

    orderRepository.save(order);

for (OrderLine orderLine : order.getOrderLines()) {
    orderLine.setOrder(order);
}
orderRepository.save(order);
```

What works in this code is:

- Creating a new parent (meaning, I don't set an orderId) with 0, 1 or more children
- Updating the parent fields and/or any of the children (in the example above, everything works fine if I don't add the second orderLine)
- Removing child rows

But what does not work, is adding a row to an existing parent. This results in the following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'ORDER_LINE_ID' cannot be null     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

which I don't understand, because I can clearly see that the orderLineId of each of the OrderLine objects is set correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure how you set your primary key for an OrderLine object in your code. This part seems to be missing here. The exception tells you, that there is no primary key for that object. Is there a specific reason for a manual strategy instead of generated values for your OrderLine primary key?

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your response.

I edited the question to include this part also. The reason I use a manual strategy for orderLine is because it is also the 'position' of the order which needs to be determined in my code.

Comment: I also tried to add a separate auto-generated primary key instead, but the ManyToOne still does not work. It says that ORDER_ID cannot be null (which is not the case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to have both order_id and order_line_id as composite key in OrderLine entity, you need to create an `@Embeddable` first:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class OrderLinePK implements Serializable {
      private Integer orderId;
      private Integer orderLineId;
 }
```

and in your OrderLine entity you change it to

```
 @EmbeddedId
 private OrderLinePk pk;

 @MapsId("orderId")
 @ManyToOne
 private Order order;
```

now everytime you need to create a new OrderLine you have to create a primary key object and assign the ID like this

```
 OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
 OrderLinePK pk = new OrderLinePK();
 pk.setOrderLineId(11);
 orderLine.setPk(pk);
 orderLine.setOrder(order);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works now